# Lottery Taxes and Relocation

Tags: united-states, taxes, lottery

If you reside in North Carolina, buy a winning lottery ticket in South Carolina in February, and you relocate to Tennessee in that same month of February, how much tax liability on the lottery winnings do you have to North Carolina if you no longer reside at the time of tax filing?

If you were employed in North Carolina for 2 months, would NC receive a portion thereof?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter where you live when you file your taxes; who has a claim on your income tax it is based on where you live and/or work when you have the income.

It can become more complex if you live in one state and win in another. But moving after you receive the money doesn't allow you to change the state tax situation. Of course getting many payments over years or decades will again make it complex.

If this is serious money, then consult a tax expert.